# FOR loop - sort by first element in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I get the following data

```
{'Value': ['A000453', 'Product AB', 5.0]}
{'Value': ['A000201', 'Product UV', 10.0]}
{'Value': ['A000900', 'Product XY', 2.0]}
```

which I can output in a loop, as follows:

```
for i in x['data']:
    print('Order:', i['Value'][0])
    print('Product:', i['Value'][1])
    print('Amount:', int(i['Value'][2]))
```

Is there any way to sort the output within the loop by the first value?

So that it looks like this at the end:

```
Order: A000201
Product: Product UV
Amount: 10

Order: A000453
Product: Product AB
Amount: 5

Order: A000900
Product: Product XY
Amount: 2
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: No, you have to sort your data before...

Comment: You can try `for i in sorted(x['data'], key=lambda x: x['Value'][0]):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `sort` with a custom key.
For example:

```py
x = [
    {'Value': ['A000453', 'Product AB', 5.0]},
    {'Value': ['A000201', 'Product UV', 10.0]},
    {'Value': ['A000900', 'Product XY', 2.0]}
    ]
x.sort(key= lambda x: x['Value'][0])

for i in x:
    print('Order:', i['Value'][0])
    print('Product:', i['Value'][1])
    print('Amount:', int(i['Value'][2]))
```

The output will be:

```py
Order: A000201
Product: Product UV
Amount: 10

Order: A000453
Product: Product AB
Amount: 5

Order: A000900
Product: Product XY
Amount: 2
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses.

The solution with x.sort(key= lambda x: x['Value'][0]) was the best for me in this case.

Answer (score 1):

in this way you can sort the list by first element:

```
data.sort(key=lambda x: x['Value'][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a key function:

```
data = [
    {'Value': ['A000453', 'Product AB', 5.0]},
    {'Value': ['A000201', 'Product UV', 10.0]},
    {'Value': ['A000900', 'Product XY', 2.0]},
]

for order, product, amount in sorted(d['Value'] for d in data):
    print('Order:', order)
    print('Product:', product)
    print('Amount:', int(amount))
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter as ig
for x, y, z in sorted(map(ig('Value'), a), key=ig(0)):
    print('Order:', x)
    print('Product:', y)
    print('Amount:', int(z))
```